# Embedding a flowchart design surface in a .net application

Tags: c#, user-interface, flowchart

I need to incorporate a flowchart design surface into an app we're developing to allow users to create what are essentially workflows/schedules. I need to be able to create my own 'shapes', set custom properties on them and possibly have a bit of logic in there too (if, while etc).

I know I need to take a look at hosting WF in the app, it looks like a good fit, but does anyone know of other designer compoments out there I could use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at these resources, both are free solutions, but compared to the commercial ones (Mindfusion, GoDiagram) they require some more development work on your side:

- [WPF Diagram Designer @ CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part4.aspx) (requires WPF)
- [Netron library](http://www.orbifold.net/default/?page_id=1272) (without WPF)

Comment: Your second link seems to have become broken.

Answer (score 3):

You should try [Visual Studio Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx2008/products/default.aspx). You are able to use the VS.NET IDE for *free*, create diagrams, export into xml/webservice/custom format etc.

> For example, you can create a tool to describe concepts that are specific to how your organization models business processes. If you are building a state chart tool, you can describe what a state is, what properties a state has, what kinds of states exist, how transitions between states are defined, and so on. A state chart that describes the status of contracts in an insurance company is superficially similar to a state chart that describes user interaction among pages on a Web site. However, the underlying concepts between the two state charts will differ significantly. By creating your own domain-specific language and custom-generated designer, you can specify exactly what state chart concepts you need in your tool.

[Start here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx/cc677260.aspx). Examples here:

- [Storyboard designer sample](http://www.codeplex.com/storyboarddesigner)
- [DSL Tools Lab](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/DSLToolsLab)

  [image: vse]
  <sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/bb933751.bb510103_storyboarddesigner_isolated_thumb(en-us,MSDN.10).jpg))</sub>